# DMARC preventing users submitting web forms

Tags: email, dns, smtp

All of the contact forms on our website put the user's actual e-mail address in as the FROM address.  The problem is that it appears our e-mail host is now checking DMARC headers and seeing that our SMTP server (Sendgrid) is not a permitted host to send FROM certain domains such as yahoo.com or gmail.com.

One hacky fix I found was to make the FROM address default to something control DNS for (user@ourdomain.com) and then put the user's actual address into the REPLY TO field, but this then causes problems with our ticketing system (Kayako) and it feels like there should be a better solution.

Any tips on dealing with this?  I'd hate to get rid of all of our contact forms and switch them to simple e-mail addresses, but apparently we've been losing a bunch of contact requests that are simply blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be to set the form to use a domain you control. Otherwise, the form submissions have the appearance of spoofed emails. You aren't a spoofer but your form submissions look exactly like them. There's not a good work around other than to send form results from a domain you control.